# BottomSheet Image Picker

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a project that requires some images to be uploaded. I have done it successfully, but the user has to click 6 buttons to get 6 images on the screen. Not very efficient, so I asked around and I was told to use imagepicker.

I have implemented this https://github.com/siralam/BSImagePicker and it makes everything easy, but I am really struggling(no clue) on how to get those image to upload to storage and have the path stored in database.

The way I know it is to get the `mimage1Uri = data.getData();` on the onActivityResult.

Could someone help me get the uri?

I apologize if you find this question too much of a burden.

```java
public class PostFragment extends Fragment implements BSImagePicker.OnMultiImageSelectedListener {

    private ImageView ivImage1, ivImage2, ivImage3, ivImage4, ivImage5, ivImage6;
    private EditText mTitle, mDescription, mPrice, mCountry, mStateProvince, mCity, mContactEmail;
    private Button mPost;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private double mProgress = 0;
    private Uri mSelectedUri;
    private Uri mSelectedUri1;
    private byte[] mUploadBytes;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false);
        ivImage1 = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_image1);
        ivImage2 = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_image2);
        ivImage3 = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_image3);
        ivImage4 = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_image4);
        ivImage5 = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_image5);
        ivImage6 = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_image6);
        mTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.input_title);


        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);


        view.findViewById(R.id.tv_multi_selection).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BSImagePicker pickerDialog = new BSImagePicker.Builder("")
                        .setMaximumDisplayingImages(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                        .isMultiSelect()
                        .setMinimumMultiSelectCount(3)
                        .setMaximumMultiSelectCount(6)
                        .build();
                pickerDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "picker");
            }
        });

        startPosting();

        return view;
    }
        public void onMultiImageSelected(List<Uri> uriList, String tag) {
        for (int i = 0; i < uriList.size(); i++) {

            if (i >= 6) return;
            ImageView iv;
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    iv = ivImage1;

                    break;
                case 1:
                    iv = ivImage2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    iv = ivImage3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    iv = ivImage4;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    iv = ivImage5;
                    break;
                case 5:
                default:
                    iv = ivImage6;
            }
            Glide.with(this).load(uriList.get(i)).into(iv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a simple as...

```
public void onMultiImageSelected(List<Uri> uriList, String tag) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < uriList.size(); i++) { 
        Uri image = uriList.get(i);
        // Do something with Uri of this image
    }
}
```